# Change TextView text

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to change my `TextView` text from the code.

This is what my xml looks like:

```
XML:
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
```

And the code:

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv1.setText("Hello");
setContentView(tv1);
```

I'm getting an error on my device and the application stops.
I tried to show a `TextView` (not connected to an XML `TextView`) and it worked.

Comment: TextView cannot be set as your parent view. You'll have to surround the TextView with a LinearLayout.

Comment: ^ correct
Show us your oncreate method, what's the name of your xml file?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Your approach is incorrect. I think it will be Null Pointer Exception (next time post log cat)

You need to specify the layout you are using first, before finding views.

**Java:**

```
// Specify the layout you are using.
setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);

// Load and use views afterwards
TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv1.setText("Hello");
```

**Kotlin:**

```
// Specify the layout you are using.
setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout)

// Load and use views afterwards
val tv1: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView1)
tv1.text = "Hello"
```

[Click Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/395614/Basic-structure-of-an-Android-project) to study exactly you want to know

Comment: @ImriPersiado Then you can accept the answer,Just by tick mark which is at left side of my answer :P

Comment: @ChrisMcJava - Shouldn't the Kotlin version using synthetic?

Comment: @AjahnCharles: Kotlinx synthetic is no longer recommended standard practice: https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/882241

Explanation from Android at Google:  https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/ala9p2/why_kotlinx_synthetic_is_no_longer_a_recommended/efdvpkg/

Answer (score 5):

remove this.. `setContentView(tv1);`

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem. My app was stopping too.
Actually, I was writing the code outside of the function/method. So to fix this problem, these lines

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv1.setText("Hello");
```

must be inside a function/method. (can be user defined)
(I am new to android studio so I don't know the reason behind the problem but I only know how to fix this. Maybe this helps new ones despite this question being 8 years old.)