# Runtime error on textView.setText(message)... Why? :-(

Tags: android, textview, runtime, settext

I'm new to Android programming. I honestly can say, I have been searching for answers just about everywhere on the web. Please help.

Here is a stackoverflow link of a typical, and the nearest to what I want to achieve
[Change TextView text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452991/change-textview-text)

My main problem is. Whenever I want to change the text of TextView object, I get a runtime error and the app is "force close". I am experience in OOP in C++ and PHP. I simply don't understand why the app terminate on textView.setText(message). Everything is defined. I even tried textView.setText("Hello"). whenever I remove this statement, the app run.

activity_main.xml (entire file)

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="MyApp.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="MyApp.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String message = "hi there";
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello_world);
    textView.setText("this is a test");

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    } // if
} // onCreate

// SKIPPED A FEW CODE

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    } // onCreateView
} // PlaceholderFragment
```

LogCat

```
06-23 20:11:42.106: W/dalvikvm(332): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
06-23 20:11:42.116: E/AndroidRuntime(332): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-23 20:11:42.116: E/AndroidRuntime(332): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{MyApp/MyApp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-23 20:11:42.116: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
06-23 20:11:42.116: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
06-23 20:11:42.116: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-23 20:11:42.116: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
06-23 20:11:42.116: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-23 20:11:42.116: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-23 20:11:42.116: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-23 20:11:42.116: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 20:11:42.116: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-23 20:11:42.116: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-23 20:11:42.116: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-23 20:11:42.116: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-23 20:11:42.116: E/AndroidRuntime(332): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-23 20:11:42.116: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at MyApp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
06-23 20:11:42.116: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-23 20:11:42.116: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
06-23 20:11:42.116: E/AndroidRuntime(332):  ... 11 more
06-23 20:11:44.826: I/Process(332): Sending signal. PID: 332 SIG: 9
```

What is *NullPointerException* and *uncaught exception*?

Again, the app runs when I remove the `setText()` line, byt terminates when included.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First, read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this Then, edit your question to explain what your stack trace is showing you. Also, please explain where you think that you are using the XML that you list here.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the link :-) I've added the names of the xml & java files, and the LogCat... I'm also new to stackoverflow, I'm unfamiliar with the layout. I thought your reply was an auto response. Sorry :-)

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653778/nullpointerexception-accessing-views-in-oncreate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` in `onCreate()`. You have not provided the contents of `res/layout/activity_main.xml` in your question.

However, your error indicates that `res/layout/activity_main.xml` does not contain a widget with `android:id="@+id/hello_world"`.

Your `res/layout/fragment_main.xml` file has such a widget, but you are not using that file in the code pasted into your question so far.

Either:

- Add a widget with the right ID to `res/layout/activity_main.xml`, or
- Move your `TextView` logic to some place that is appropriate, based upon where you are trying to use `res/layout/fragment_main.xml`

Comment: thanks for responding! :-) I apologize for lack of information. I'm learning to know what is important to provide. I am avoiding a long, long post like this :-)  anyway, I have updated the xml files, and I don't understand where to put my TextView in the activity_main.xml, which is a FrameLayout. Mus I add the widget with the same @+id/hello_world as in fragment_main.xml?

Comment: @sacre: You need to decide whether the activity or the fragment will be managing this `TextView`. You then put the widget in the right layout based upon that decision, and you put your Java code for the `TextView` in the right class based upon that decision.

Comment: you are both having me derailed and making great sense... You suggest `TextView` must move to `FrameLayout` to use `MainActivity` in java, **OR** move `textView.setText(message)` to `PlaceholderFragment extends fragment { PlaceholderFragment () { onCreateView() { textView.SetText(...) }}}`

Comment: I can't move my logic into the static PlaceholderFragment, it complains :-(  What is an appropriate place in the default `MainActivity.java`? I'm curious about this option... In the meanwhile I'll try moving TextView to activity_main.xml

Comment: Thank you!! :-D `textView.setText("string")` run great when `<TextView />` is in `<FrameLayout />` in activity_main.xml